# get request have no responses in expressjs

Tags: node.js, get, mongoose, request

Im trying to get a response from a simple route to check if a client exist in my database... is really simple but when the GET request is fired, it's not resolved and never show any response.

This is the code for the route:

```
router.get('/clientes/:client_id', function (req, res) {
  Cliente.find({ _id: req.params.client_id }, function(err, cliente) {
    if(!cliente) {
      res.status(404).json({ statusMsg: 'El cliente no existe' });
    } else if(err) {
      res.json({ error: err });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ cliente: cliente, statusMsg: 'Ok' });
    }
  });
}); // end: router.get clientes
```

Pretty simple, but when i run `curl http://localhost:8080/omi/v1/clientes/2345` (the id is arbitrary, is just one test to get a 404 response) for a simple get request, i get this in my server logger (morgan): `GET /omi/v1/clientes/10 - - ms - -`, Because i need to cancel the job.

So i read one, two, three times the code, searched on google and don't get the problem. Anyway my english is not really good too, so maybe i dont make a complete search.

Comment: Are you sure that your route handler is being executed? Add a `console.log('test');` before `Cliente.find()` and see if it logs that to your console.

Comment: @mscdex i added a `console.log('it works');` and it's fired when the request is send, so yes, the route are being executed... is weird, i dont see any problem in the code..